# Unexpected matlab behaviour when using vectorised assignment

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I've come across some unexpected behaviour in matlab that I can't make sense of when performing vectorised assignment:

```
>> q=4;

>> q(q==[1,3,4,5,7,8])
The logical indices contain a true value outside of the array bounds.

>> q(q==[1,3,4,5,7,8])=1

q =

     4     0     1
```

Why does the command `q(q==[1,3,4,5,7,8])` result in an error, but the command `q(q==[1,3,4,5,7,8])=1` work? And how does it arrive at `4  0  1` being the output?

Comment: Let's see a simpler example `a = 4;` then `a(2)` will give you that error and `a(2)=1` will be okay.

Comment: Assigning to an out-of-bounds index will expand the array and write to that index. Reading an out-of-bounds index is an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between `q(i)` and `q(i)=a` is that the former must produce the value of an array element; if `i` is out of bounds, MATLAB chooses to give an error rather than invent a value (good choice IMO). And the latter must write a value to an array element; if `i` is out of bounds, MATLAB chooses to extend the array so that it is large enough to be able to write to that location (this has also proven to be a good choice, it is useful and used extensively in code). Numeric arrays are extended by adding zeros.

In your specific case, `q==[1,3,4,5,7,8]` is the logical array `[0,0,1,0,0,0]`. This means that you are trying to index `i=3`. Since `q` has a single value, reading at index 3 is out of bounds, but we can write there. `q` is padded to size 3 by adding zeros, and then the value 1 is written to the third element.

Comment: Thank you for the really clear explanation. I make use of that feature quite a bit, not sure why it was such a mystery here!